# Function calling itself within a await/promise context - Cannot destructure property `response` of 'undefined' or 'null'. at eval

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm failing to understand the error I get and to achieve some "promise"related actions in javascript.

Bascially, I would like to implement a third party API this way:

- I make call to the api (see pollApi)
- if it times out within 60 seconds I get a log telling me it timed out: THIS WORKS
- if I get a 500 response, I retrigger the call (once only)
- If i get a 429 (too many concurrent calls), I must wait 10 seconds then retrigger the same call (as many times here as needed until i don't get a 429)

The script IS working when i make just a few calls (that is to say when there is no concurrent calls), but as soon as i have concurrent calls (code 429), then the bit handling this scenario in my code IS NOT WORKING. And the error I keep getting is coming from a global catch is:

```
[CURL] Rejected because non 200: 429 body: You're sending requests a bit too fast! Please slow down your requests

Faced with error 429 (all available slots on API within the authorized nb of concurrent calls) : retrying in 10 seconds...

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `response` of 'undefined' or 'null'. at eval
```

Interestingly enough, the execution seems to NEVER enter the `if ( response ) { log("body is ", body);` I put roughly at the start to check what was happening.

I think the bug must come from me not being really very good at await, promise and all ...

**script.js**

```
 const handler = ErrorHandlingHOF(async function(event, context, callback) {
   try {
    const THIRDPARTY_API_RETRY_INTERVAL_ON_429 = 10 * 1000;
    const THIRDPARTY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000;
    let timerId;    
    let revisited = {};

    let { response, body } = await runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url);    
    let json;
    if ( response ) {
      log("body is ", body);
      json = JSON.parse(body);              
      log('runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url) gives us : ', json);
    } 

    function pollApi(url) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         let timeout = false;
         curl(url).then(function({ response, body }) {
           if (!timeout) {
             resolve({response, body})
           }
         }).catch(reject);
         setTimeout(function() {
           timeout = true;
           reject(new Error("Request to URL ", url, " timed out"))
         }, THIRDPARTY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
       });
     }

    function runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url) {

      return pollApi(url).then(function({response, body}) {
        log("body is : ", body);
        return body;
      }).catch(function(e) {          
        let { response, body } = e;

        if (response.statusCode === 500) {
          if (!revisited[url]) { 
            log("Faced with error 500, retrying once", url);
            revisited[url] = true;
            runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url); 
          } else {
            log("Faced with error 500 already once, so we do retry the url any more");
          }
        }

        if (response.statusCode === 429  ) {           
          return delay(THIRDPARTY_API_RETRY_INTERVAL_ON_429).then(() => {
            log("Faced with error 429 (all available slots on API within the authorized nb of concurrent calls) : retrying in 10 seconds ", url);
            runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url);
          })

        }
      });
    }

   } catch (e) {
    log(
      "Error occured while trying to get infos on fn xxxxxxxxxx",
      e
    );
  }

 });

 export { handler };
```

**Supporting_functions.js**

```
export function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
export function curl(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(
      {
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers: {             
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Error while placeing request");
          reject(error);
        } else if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
          console.log("[CURL] Rejected because non 200: ", response.statusCode, 'body: ', body);
          reject({ response, body });
        } else {
          console.log("resolved");
          resolve({ response, body });
        }
      }
    ).on("error", function(error) {
      console.log("Error during connection <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", error);
    });
  });
}

export function ErrorHandlingHOF(handler) {
  return function(...fnArgs) {
    try {
      return handler(...fnArgs);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Exception occurred in the lambda handler', error);      
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The promise returned by `runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url)` very often resolves with nothing, i.e. `undefined`. And it *never* resolves with an `{response, body}` object?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I get everything fine when there is no error 429. so this bit of code works but as soon as I "enter" the 429 "road", i.e when i receive a "too many request" response from the third party, then in that case, I ALWAYS get the error message "Cannot destructure property `response` of 'undefined' or 'null'. at eval"

Comment: It doesn't work when there is *any* error, regardless of the specific status code. And I really doubt it works fine when there is no error, since you only return the `body` and then try to access the body's `.body` and `.response` properties.

Comment: Ho what i considered as « working » was the fact i could at least print/log the actual json response of the third party API thanks to the Line « log(‘body is’, body). I can see it’s real stuff coming from an external API/server. But everytime the execution enters 429 then I don’t get what I would like to do i.e. retrigger the function itself: I simply get the error message I mentioned

Comment: As far as only returning the body, I tried returning both but I think it did not work or at least I did it wrong, but anyway where I am returning things (response, body...) is not the case on which the error message appears. The error message I mention occurs when I don’t actually return body or response but where I try to return a delay() fn

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But the promise created by that `delay().then(…)` fulfills with `undefined`, since you don't `return` anything.

Comment: That s the issue yes: how can I ask the code to retrigger itself with a 10second wait/timeout and await again the result (maybe a 209, a 500 or again a 429...if a 429 retrigger again and so on...)

Comment: How to return sth that can be acted upon then ? Sorry I’m quite rookie in js so my choice of words is maybe not ideal.

Comment: You already are retriggering the function. You just are ignoring the result you get, and `return` nothing.

Comment: So where should I add this return response/ or body then ?

Comment: With promises, the first rule of development is that *every single function* must return (a promise for) a value. This especially applies to `then` and `catch` callbacks, and in your `catch` callback to every individual branch case. You'll want to return the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Could you share some code because I fail to understand : indeed if i return body or response or sth like that, then my line where The function calls itself again ( delay { runUrlOnThirdPartyUrl() } will never be executed right? Because i’ll have already returned body or response, isn’t that correct? I mean I understand the need to return , that’s why I did not just write delay() but return delay()

Comment: Yes, that `return` in front of the `delay().…` is correct, what is missing is a `return` in the `then` callback function

Comment: One `return` is not enough, the other cases are still not working either.

Comment: Right: I added 2 returns: one inside the   if (response.statusCode === 500) { return  runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url);  } and one if (response.statusCode === 429) { return  runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url);  } . Thanks a lot, Now I'm trying to get the "successful cases" where I currently do return body, and make it return {response, boyd} so that it's caught by the block let { response, body } = await runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url);        
    if ( response ) {
      log("body is ", body);
      json = JSON.parse(body);              
      log('runUrlOnThirdPartyApi(url) gives us : ', json);
    }

Comment: You will also need to `return` something (or `throw`?) from the `else` branches

Comment: For the else { log("Faced with error 500 already once, so we do retry the url any more");}, I'll trigger another function yet to build called fallbackFnIfthirdPartyApiCallFails().

Comment: Yes, but you'll want to `return` its result as well :-) And don't forget the other else case: when the status is neither 500 nor 429.

Comment: And for the other 2 elses here else if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {  console.log("[CURL] Rejected because non 200: ", response.statusCode, 'body: ', body); reject({ response, body }); } else {console.log("resolved");resolve({ response, body }); : for the first one, i don't want to  really do something apart from logging a message , and for the second one it's working already (I see in my logs resolved)

Comment: ok thanks for the big hlep, I'll check all the cases indeed

Comment: what's the convention when you only want to log something (for example in the cases of an error that is not 429 or 500) but I need to still return something ? should I return an empty object such as return({}) to remain consistent with the fact that on each "cases" I always need to rteturn something that is an object ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't return an empty object that doesn't work - it's the same as with returning `undefined`, it fail somewhere down the chain. Instead, just throw an exception - you're catching and logging that anyway.

Comment: OK I see, makes sense. thanks